# Search and Replace in highlighted text returns Trailing Characters error in neovim

Tags: neovim

I have a block of code in NeoVim and try to do a search and replace:

1. CTRL+V Visual mode.
2. 'J' multiple times for a block of lines
3. ':' starts with :'<,'>
4. add 's/abc/xyz/g
5. Enter

Result:
Trailing characters /abc/xyz/g

Answer (score 0):

Facepalm

Remove the '%' in higlighted block:

```
':s/abc/xyz/g'
```

Instead of:

```
':%s/abc/xyz/g'
```